# ElementAPI: How to trigger the Custom service php file when a endpoint is loaded

Tags: plugin-development, craft3, plugin-elementapi

I am Using Craft 3.3.11 version

I have a php file in

> *plugin/elementapi/src/services/EapiServices.php*

and the same file within

> *vendor/craftcms/element-api/src/services/EapiServices.php*

When I hit the *http://localhost:9001/index.php/api/news.json* 
EapiServices.php from vendor folder is triggered instead of EapiServices.php file from plugin folder.

Can someone help to to make the services files to work within the plugin directory?

Comment: Have you check your namespacing?

Comment: Yes, my namespace is `craft\element\services` and class name is `EapiServices` but still its throwing "Class 'craft\\elementapi\\services\\EapiService' not found"